# How i to move cursor from one edit text another when keyboard backspace key pressing Android

Tags: android, events, android-softkeyboard

i am currently using 3 edit text fields and move their cursor forward
**(edittext1--> edittext2--> edittext3)** when **edittext input length==1**

and i want to do it's reverse method (after delete text move cursor backward 
 **(edittext1<--edittext2<--edittext3)**) when i pressing keyboard backspace

output 
[image: Activity look like this]

my code is this

```
 public EditText otp1, otp2, otp3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_otp_box);

        otp1 = findViewById(R.id.otp1);
        otp2 = findViewById(R.id.otp2);
        otp3 = findViewById(R.id.otp3);

        otp1.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {

            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if (otp1.getText().length() == 1) {
                    otp2.requestFocus();
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        otp2.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

                if (otp2.getText().length() == 1) {
                    otp3.requestFocus();
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        otp3.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

                if (otp3.getText().length() == 1) {
                    hideSoftKeyboard(v);
                    return false;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

    }

    public void hideSoftKeyboard(View view) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
    }
```

**xml**

```
 <LinearLayout

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/otp1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/edit_txt_border_color"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLength="1"
                android:text=""
                android:hint="X"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/otp2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/edit_txt_border_color"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLength="1"
                android:text=""
                android:hint="X"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/otp3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/edit_txt_border_color"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLength="1"
                android:text=""
                android:hint="X"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `requestFocus()` method in text change listener:

```
    opt1 = findViewById(R.id.opt1);
    opt1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (s.toString().length() == 1) {
                opt2.requestFocus();
            }
        }
    });

    opt2 = findViewById(R.id.opt2);
    opt2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (s.toString().length() == 1) {
                opt3.requestFocus();
            }

            if (s.toString().length() == 0) {
                opt1.requestFocus();
            }
        }
    });

    opt3 = findViewById(R.id.opt3);
    opt3.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (s.toString().length() == 0) {
                opt2.requestFocus();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **`addTextChangedListener()`** if your `EditText` is empty than move focus to previous `EditText`

**SAMPLE CODE**

Try this

```
    otp1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(otp1.getText().toString())){
                otp1.requestFocus();
            }else {
                otp2.requestFocus();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
    otp3.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(otp2.getText().toString())){
                otp2.requestFocus();
            }else {
                // you logic
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
    otp2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(otp2.getText().toString())){
                otp1.requestFocus();
            }else {
                otp3.requestFocus();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank for you support. your code is working  when I change if and else condition vice versa